Restoring WhatsApp DB
I changed devices (phones) and carriers. I kept the number (so it was ported).
The old phone had a regular nano-SIM card in it.
The new one got an eSIM (not a physical card).
I want to transfer the chat history of the WhatsApp that is on the old device to the one that is on the new one. But since I no longer have an active SIM for the old device it cannot connect the WhatsApp to a number (cannot register).
I managed to get the WhatsApp database from the old device but don't see an option of transfer it in the WhatsApp on the new device.
What are my options to resolve it?

You could try to restore as given in the answer here or the answer below that

I cannot follow the given answer you refernced in the likn because my old phone, from which I need to transfer the back, has no longer has an active SIM card. So WhatsApp on this (old) phone can't register. I do have the local back from that old phone. I have it on a computer, so how do I transfer it to the WhatsApp on the new phone?

Above comment posted as question here

What is the default path in Google Drive where the periodical backup is saved?. Maybe I can find an old one.

https://www.androidpolice.com/find-whatsapp-backups-google-drive/#:~:text=Open%20Google%20Drive.,last%20time%20you%20updated%20it.
